# <empty path> is not a valid path to the kernel headers?

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, vmware

**System Information**

```
Host - Windows 10
VMware - 11.1.2
Guest - CentOS 7
```

I  installed kernel-headers using yum since during the installation of `vmware-tools` I get a message

> "Searching for a valid kernel header path... The path "" is not a
>   valid path to the 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 kernel headers. Would you like
>   to change it?".

I have following packages installed

> - kernel-tools-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
> - kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
> - kernel-devel-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64
> - kernel-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64
> - kernel-headers-3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64

Then again I tried to install the `vmware-tools`, getting same message

> Searching for a valid kernel header path... The path "" is not a valid
>   path to the 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 kernel headers. Would you like to
>   change it? [yes]
>
> Enter the path to the kernel header files for the 3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64 
>   kernel? /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-229.14.1.el7.x86_64/include/linux

I have tried below paths

- /usr/include
- /usr/include/linux
- /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64
- /usr/src/kernels/3.10.0-123.13.2.el7.x86_64/include

But vmware-tools tells me none of them are valid paths to the kernel headers. Surely, one of these had to be the directory vmware-tools is looking for?

Comment: Try doing a `uname -a` to find the exact version of the kernel you're running, and then installing the EXACT matching headers. For example: `kernel-headers-3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64`.

Comment: i have installed the matching kernel after doing uname -a

Comment: yum -y install *3.10.0-229.el7.x86_64*

Comment: I just installed `kernel-devel` and `kernel-headers`, ran the `vmware-tools` script, answered the questions correctly and it all just worked.